# Find the norm of linear functional $f(x) = \int_{-1}^1 sx(s)\,ds$ on $ L_1[-1,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Find the norm of linear functional 
>   $$f(x) = \int_{-1}^1 sx(s)\,ds,\quad x\in L_1[-1,1]$$

Firstly I try to show boundedness and so I need to find any $M>0$  such that $|f(x)|\le M\|x\|_1$. As shown below, I used Hölder's inequality for norm in $L^1$; I should find right side as $L^1$ but it was   $L^2$ norm. How can  I obtain $L^1$ norm on the right?

---

$f$ is linear and bounded functional.

$$f(x) = \int_{-1}^1 s x(s) ds, \quad x \in L_1[-1,1]$$

$$\begin{align}
|f(x)| & = \left| \int_{-1}^1 s x(s) ds \right| \\
& \le \int_{-1}^1 |s x(s)| ds \\
& \le \sqrt{\int_{-1}^1 |s|^2 ds} \cdot \sqrt{\int_{-1}^1 |x(s)|^2 ds} \\
& = \left. \frac{|s|^3}{3} \right|_{-1}^1 \sqrt{\int_{-1}^1 |x(s)|^2 ds} \\
& = \underbrace{\left( \frac13 - \frac13 \right)}_{= 0} \cdot \underbrace{\sqrt{\int_{-1}^1 |x(s)|^2 ds}}_{= ?}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

Since $|s| \leq 1$ for $s \in [-1,1]$, one could use the inequalities
$$ \big|\,f(x)\,\big| \leq \int_{-1}^{1} \big|\,s x(s)\,\big| ds \leq \int_{-1}^{1} \big|\,x(s)\,\big| ds = \big|\big|\,x\,\big|\big|_{L^1},$$
which show that $f$ is a bounded linear functional on $L^1[-1,1]$ of norm at most $1$.
To show $||f||$ is exactly $1$ we use consider the $L^1[-1,1]$ function

$$x(s) =
\begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $0\leq x\leq1$} \\
-1, & \text{if $-1\leq x<0$},
\end{cases}$$
which shows $||f||\geq \left|\int_{-1}^1sx(s)ds\right|=\left|\int_{-1}^1 |s|ds\right|=1$, making $||f||=1$.